# Generating permutations of a 25-th element set, is it possible on the computer?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, subset

Is it realistic to implement an algorithm that requires generating all permutations of a 25-th element set on our computer? All the subsets of such as set?

Comment: What is the formula to calculate the number of permutations?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the algorithm and why it would require the full set of permutations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not, unless you have some special compact representation.

There are 25! = 15511210043330985984000000 possible permutations of a 25 element set, i.e. way more than you can ever represent on a computer.

As for subsets, that's much more feasible. There are only 2^25 = 33554432 of those. You'll probably want to use bitfields to speed things up and save memory, but it's definitely doable.

Comment: Depending on the application, it might be possible to present the permutations implicitly and do calculations on a large number in parallel. Even taking a single bit for each permutation is infeasible.